# Small white growth on indoor plant pot and in soil

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

After I potted my indoor Fiddle Leaf Fig tree - a few days later I noticed a strange white growth or webbing of some sort alone the bottom of the pot where the water would drain. I’ve been trying to look up different pest infestations but nothing really matches what I am seeing in my plant pot. Is also in the soil between the soil and the pot. Is this mold? Fungus? Eggs? Not sure what to do. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXzC1.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is salts from the ceramic. They will reappear every time it is dried for an unknown period. Not a problem for the plant. To prove this you can bake it in the oven and allow to cool, which would kill all garden pests.